# icloud photo Synced is not showing

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have iPhone 8 with iOS 13.2 and iTunes version Version 12.10.2.3
but the option to add photos(photo Synced) in iPhone is not showing
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to sync photos with a Mac or windows laptop?

Comment: @HimsaraGallege the font seems to be of Windows..  in fact the menu itself is in the app, not in menu bar.

Comment: I am using Window 10

Answer (score 3):

The message is self explanatory. iCloud for photos syncing is "on". You should access the photos using iCloud for Windows and iPhone's Photos.app.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204283
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/icloud/9pktq5699m62?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

See these for more info.

- https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT205323
- [How to download orginal photos from iCloud Photo Library to PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180415/how-to-download-orginal-photos-from-icloud-photo-library-to-pc)